# AppBar se sobrepondo ao conteúdo do resto da Activity

Tags: android, xml

Estou fazendo uns exercícios do mas na hora de executar, a barra sempre fica em cima do conteúdo da Activity.

**Print de como está por enquanto**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo vai o meu arquivo `content_formulario.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:hint="Nome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:hint="Endereço"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:hint="Telefone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:hint="Site"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:max="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Salvar"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isto? Obrigado.

Comment: Naldson, poderia colocar o seu `styles.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:hint="Nome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:hint="Endereço"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:hint="Telefone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:hint="Site"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:max="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Salvar"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Precisamos adicionar um `Layout` para comportar os componentes de Tela.